# "this" is referring to an object that is not in fact the one that is using "this"

Tags: c#, this, nullreferenceexception

While debugging, my program crashed with an error stating that there was a null reference. The weird thing was that on the line that it had crashed on, it is running a method in a different static class and one of the parameters is filled with "this" which should mean that it is feeding the object that is doing the calling but when I hover over the "this", it isn't the calling object but an entirely different object of a different class type.

Does anyone know or have any kind of explanation as to how using "this" could possibly have the "this" be an object that is not even the same type as the calling class?

Here is the method in question.

```
public void UpdateLight()
    { DoUpdateLight(); }

    protected virtual void DoUpdateLight()
    {
        if (isActive)
        {
            Systems.Lighting.Instance.SetSpotLight(
                this,
                (int)(owner.GetEyeHeight - owner.GetHeight * 0.25f),
                lightRange,
                owner.visionAngleHorizontal,
                owner.visionAngleVertical,
                owner.GetGridNumber,
                owner.parentFloor.floorLevel,
                lightStrength,
                lightDecay,
                lightMaxTiles,
                800);

            RemoveLights();

            litObjectsPrev = litObjects;
            litObjects = new List<ILightable>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: an example code would make it easier to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've edited the OP to include the method that the null reference error happened on. The DoUpdateLight() is called by the UpdateLight() method which is part of an interface that is implemented into the class.

Comment: Are you sure owner is not null?

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm positive the owner is not null. I am however using threading but that doesn't open up any explanation to how one class can assign "this" to an entirely different class. Especially in the given method.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

> Does anyone know or have any kind of explanation as to how using "this" could possibly have the "this" be an object that is not even the same type as the calling class?

Yes. `this` could not necessarily be the class itself. It could be because of inheritance. Which means that the type of `this` is actually its child.

Consider running this code snippet (Console app) below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace thisSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BaseClass b = getClass("Child");

            b.SayHelloAndMyType();
        }

        static BaseClass getClass(string name)
        {
            BaseClass returnValue = null;
            switch (name)
            {
                case "Base":
                    returnValue = new BaseClass();
                    break;
                case "Child":
                    returnValue = new ChildClass();
                    break;
                default:
                    returnValue = new BaseClass();
                    break;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }


    class BaseClass
    {
        private const string NAME = "Base class";

        public virtual string GetName()
        {
            return NAME;
        }

        public virtual void SayHelloAndMyType()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from " + this.GetName() + " and my type is " + this.GetType().ToString()); //this.GetName() could be "Base class" or not. Depending on what instance it really is "this" (Base or Child)
        }
    }

    class ChildClass : BaseClass
    {
        private const string NAME = "Child class";

        public override string GetName()
        {
            return NAME;
        }
    }
}
```

Now as to why your app crashed because of the NullReferenceException, it can only be answered if there is a stack trace as to where that exception was thrown.

Comment: Thank you for your example. However, the class that the program claimed the "this" was was not an inherited class or even a base class. They both share a common base class but are completely different types of children from a similar base.